How to create, in a jupyter notebook, an Interactive 2D hystogram with 3D datas
The number of occurrence of an event that depends of many parameters have been calculated.
And I would like to create an interactive 2D histogram in a jupyter notebook.
To keep things simple in this question, there are three parameters (par1,par2,par3). The 3D histogram is simulated with the following instruction :: all_datas=np.random.rand(5,10,20)*100. the numbers of bins are 5, 10, 20 for par1, par2, par3, respectively.
The 2D histogram for par1 and par2 is plotted in ax0 with these instructions.
fig,(ax0,ax1)=plt.subplots(1,2)
c=ax0.pcolor(np.sum(all_datas, axis=2).transpose())
plt.show;

When the mouse is over a specific 2D bin (so, par1=i_par and par2=j_par are fixed) in ax0, how is it possible to plot a par3 1D histogram of this bin (all_datas(i_par,j_par,:)) in ax1.
Obviously, the problem is not the creation of 1D histogram but the interactivity : How can I do to have this 1D histogram plot in ax1 depending on mouse position on ax0)

I haven't thought through all the details, but since you specified you need interactivity, you'll need to install and use ipympl via  %matplotlib ipympl at the start of the cell.

Thanks for answer and this information. I will try : mpl_interactions[jupyter] (https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html)

I see in their documentation they feature ipympl clearly. Thankfully. That is helpful; there's a lot of gaps out there right now, especially in regards to animations, which need ipympl, too. And all the content with old ways still around make it difficult for newcomers to find. Anyway, I have referred to that mpl_interactions package for Zooming as it is nice for that.
